# How to read a json file and write the data to csv file in python3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.7

Getting JSONDecodeError when trying to read a json file and write to a csv file using Python 3?

I'm have written a script to fetch the data from mongodb and the result got is converted to flattened json format, stored it to a json file - data_flatten_json.json. But when I try to read the same json file and convert them to csv file - data.csv. Facing issue

```
with open('data_flatten_json.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


f = open('data.csv')
csv_file = csv.writer(f)
for item in data:
    csv_file.writerow(item)

f.close()
```

data_flatten_json.json contains data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5cdd5ea359af317620aae420"
    },
    "email": "abc@domain.com",
    "user_info": {
        "name": "abc",
        "city": "Bengaluru",
        "age_group": "36 - 40 years",
        "marital_status": "Married",
        "c_shaving_hurt": "Strongly agree",
        "c_shaving_convenience": "Strongly agree",
        "c_shaving_skip": "Agree",
        "c_shaving_groomed": "Disagree",
        "c_shaving_feel": "Strongly agree"
    },
    "studies": {
        "questions": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5cdd3f5a59af317620aae3a6"
                },
                "image_url": "https://video.svg",
                "question_order_number": 1,
                "question_type": "text",
                "question": "How do you shave or trim your beard?",
                "answer_type": "video",
                "question_videos": [],
                "answers": "",
                "updated_at": {
                    "$date": 1558003546858
                },
                "created_at": {
                    "$date": 1558003546858
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5cde5bc559af310ea00c42b7"
    },
    "email": "xyz@domain.com",
    "user_info": {
        "name": "xyz",
        "city": "Togo",
        "age_group": "18 - 21 years",
        "marital_status": "Divorced",
        "c_shaving_hurt": "Agree",
        "c_shaving_convenience": "Strongly agree",
        "c_shaving_skip": "Neither agree not disagree",
        "c_shaving_groomed": "Agree",
        "c_shaving_feel": "Disagree"
    },
    "studies": {
        "questions": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5cdd3f5a59af317620aae3a6"
                },
                "image_url": "https://video.svg",
                "question_order_number": 1,
                "question_type": "text",
                "question": "How do you shave or trim your beard?",
                "answer_type": "video",
                "question_videos": [],
                "answers": "",
                "updated_at": {
                    "$date": 1558003546858
                },
                "created_at": {
                    "$date": 1558003546858
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am expecting a csv output.

Facing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/srinivas/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/TEST1.py", line 66, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 30 column 2 (char 1146)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input is not valid JSON, it contains *two* JSON objects. Either use a JSON array to wrap them. Or remove one of the objects.

This is not possible:

```
        ]
    }
}{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5cde5bc559af310ea00c42b7"
    }
```